# How to discover spree e-commerce models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, spree

I am new to `ruby on rails` and `spree e-commerce` too. what i want is to see all the models that manipulates this e-commerce framework `poduct.rb`, `order.rb` ... to understand relationships between all of them. But I did not find them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by generating your domain model:

- [Generate ERD](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd)
- [Look at the source code](https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/core/app/models/spree)

This will generate a complete domain model of the project you are working on by looking at the relationships between the models.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you! generate ERD is  a very good idea but when tried to generate it not all the model are genrated and i have lots of  warnnigs such as: "Warning: Ignoring invalid association :taxons on Spree::Promotion::Rules::Taxon (model Spree::Taxon exists, but is not included in domain)"

Comment: Maybe the gem I provided doesn't have support for rails engines.
You could als try this: https://github.com/preston/railroady
With the command: `rake diagram:all_with_engines`

This will generate a database diagram with all relations.

Answer (score 1):

It 's ok I found it under `.rvm/gems/ruby2.2.0/gems/spree_core-2.4.3` but there are a lot of models its difficult to understand the relationships between all of them is there any documentation that do better?